# How to make ontouchlistener work in such way it respond different when holding and when only touching?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have a button , on which calling onTouchListener , I want to set different behavior . 1. if it is being pressed ,
           2.when user just touch the button

Comment: create an OnLongClickListener for this Button

Comment: button does somethings, that is not properly handled by OnLongClickListener properly, that's why i am using onTouchListener

Comment: by number 2 you mean a simple short click, i.e. press and release?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off using an OnLongClickListener rather than an onTouch.  You can set one just like an onClick and it will call you when a press and hold has occurred.

If you did want to implement it via onTouch, you'd set a timer in the touchDown.  If the user has a touchUp, cancel the timer.  If not, when the timer goes off it is now a touch and hold and you perform whatever behavior you wanted to.